# How to add output of second query with the output of First Query

Tags: postgresql

I have two different queries. Can i add (Column Wise not row wise) the output of second query with the first query? Both have different columns and different output.

Union will not work in my case as both queries give different number of outputs.

For Example -

```
Select count(BATCH), ID from tableA group by ID;

Count(1), ID
2,       123
3,       234

Select Count(STATEMENT), ID from tableB group by ID;

Count(1),  ID
4,         123
5,         234
```

I want output as

```
Count(1) Count (1) ID
2         3        123
3         4        234
```

Comment: *"Both have different columns and different output."* - Does that mean column ID has different name and values in A and B?

Answer (score 1):

You can join the two queries:

```
select table_a.count_a, 
       table_b.count_b, 
       table_a.id
from ( 
    Select count(BATCH) as count_a, 
           ID 
    from tableA 
    group by ID
) as table_a
  join (
    Select Count(STATEMENT) as count_b, ID 
    from tableB 
    group by ID;
  ) as table_b on b.id = a.id;
```

Note that if one query returns IDs that are not present in the other, the above would exclude those rows. If that can happen, use a `full join` instead of `join`